# Disable button in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.dataTables.js plugin, with this i have created a double table where i can add the rows from one table to another table and remove vice versa.How can i disable the add and remove buttons.Please verify the image for more idea.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
$.fn.doubletable = function (opts) {    
var node_img_remove = "<img src='" + root + "images/"+theme+"ico_moove-down.png' class='button_remove' style='float:none; cursor:pointer;' title='"+titleRemove+"' alt='"+titleRemove+"' />";
var node_img_add = "<img src='" + root + "images/"+theme+"ico_moove-up.png' class='button_add' style='float:none; cursor:pointer;' title='"+titleAdd+"' alt='"+titleAdd+"' />";
}
```

Comment: What is the element that you want to disable .. the class belongs to an image .. is this image in an anchor tag?

Comment: Did you upvote my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this button has a class apply the necessary style to disable these buttons on make it unclickable. This can be done with jQuery.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../JS/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.disable').attr("disabled", true);
        //$('#Button1').prop("disabled", true);  //for disabling elemnt by id
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="disable" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you are looking for? This will disable the button element on load. Similarly you can call it whenever you need.

Comment: i am looking for the same, the button class is "button_add" which is declared in the plugin not in my local class.if i use with ur answer its not working :( , can you see the above code and tell me how to disable that button or image..???

Comment: when do you want the images to be disabled .. just give in id to the element and disable it.

Comment: i have to disable it dynamically in other js file, i tried to disable like this:
$('.button_add').prop("disabled",true);

Comment: Is this at the time of loading?

Comment: No, its not at the time of loading, i need to check a condition and disable it

Comment: @Rajsekhar : Sometimes prop may not be supported in previous jquery versions and cause errors, so to disable try $('.button_add').attr("disabled", true);

Comment: try  $('.button_add').attr("disabled", true);
@Gaurav123 : +1

Comment: Thankf for your answers @Gaurav123 and AJ